# Instantiate a class and use it in a different class

Tags: java, object

I'm getting into object oriented programming and for a college assignment I have to make a simple Memory game. The memory game itself i have created and it works.

Now I want to make it so that the user has to 'login' so that I can save his username later on.
I'm stuck at this because i'm still getting familiar with object on when to use them etc.

What i wanna achieve is when the user presses the 'Login', the current Frame closes, and a new frame opens. As soon as i do that i instantiate a new `Person person = new Person()`. But how would i achieve it so that when the new person is created, i can access him from outside of that class?

My current code

```
public void confirmLogin(ActionEvent e)
{
    //When user presses login button
    //Save the username so i can present it on the next Frame
    //Create a new Person and set the username input as his username.

    Person person= new Person();
    person.setUsername(usernameField.getText());

    //Open the new frame
    //In this frame i want to access person.

    Program program = new Program();
    this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));


}
```

Program class :

```
public class Program extends JFrame {

JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel();

Program() {
    this.setSize(200,200);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);

    //How do i access person from here?
    usernameLabel.setText("Username");
    this.add(usernameLabel);


    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

I'm not entirely sure if i got the hang of it and if it is possible to access `person` out of the scope after initialising it.

Comment: if i was you, i would create a static object of Person, and i will retrieve the credentials from it

Comment: To do this properly, you have to save Person instance somewhere. Or save person login data. If you only need this for session scope, create a singleton class which would be shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have the code now, no, `Person` cannot be accessed outside of the scope of `confirmLogin()`. If you want it to be accessible to `Program` then I would just pass it as an argument.

Eg :

```
public void confirmLogin(ActionEvent e){
    Person user = new Person();
    person.setUsername(usernameField.getText());

    Program program = new Program(user);

    this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
}

public class Program extends JFrame {
    JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel();

    Program(Person user) {
        this.setSize(200,200);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);

        // Get the username from the user
        usernameLabel.setText(user.getUsername());
        this.add(usernameLabel);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Injecting `Person` into `Program` is also a nice solution.

Comment: This helped me! Thanks alot for reminding me i could pass arguments into another class. From here i can access the user ! I will leave the question open for a while because people are still answering i'm curious to more answers.

Comment: @markspace There's tons of options, as you also pointed out. It really just depends on OPs use cases of `Person` and `Program` and what mostly clearly conveys the intent.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to do this, but the most common I think would be to create a class to hold on to the value of `Person` so you can access it later.

For example, you could use a static field in your main class:

```
public class Main {

  public static Person logon;

  public static void main( String... args ) {
    // starts your program
  }
}
```

Or you could use a class that you instantiate, for example if you have a class of type `MemoryGame` that you are using for the game itself.

```
public class MemoryGame {

  private Person logon;

  public void setLogon( Person p ) { logon = p; }
  public Person getLogon() { return logon; }
}
```

Of course you should set these values in your confirmLogin method.

```
public void confirmLogin(ActionEvent e)
{
    //When user presses login button
    //Save the username so i can present it on the next Frame
    //Create a new Person and set the username input as his username.

    Person person= new Person();
    person.setUsername(usernameField.getText());

    Main.logon = person;            // <- here
    // or...
    memoryGame.setLogon( person );  // or here
```

`memoryGame` will need to be injected (set) before calling the `confirmLogon` method.  Static fields are a little easier, using injection is considered better practice and provides better separation of concerns.

Comment: Thanks ! I will take a look into injecting !